# Clone a Gtk.Button from gjs

Tags: gtk, gjs

How would I go about cloning any widget from gjs, similar to the C response given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030603/1829961? I have not been able to find a way to call `list_properties` although it *is* listed in the `GModule` gir file. Or do I have to use GIRepository, manually walk the GIR type hierarchy, emulating that which `g_object_class_list_properties` is supposed to do? Or another straight forward way I'm totally missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ptomato/c4245c77d375022a43c5) is some code that will do that.

It takes a similar approach to the quesion you linked, but since there is no `G_OBJECT_GET_CLASS()` in GJS, it uses `GIRepository` instead -- which is an extra dependency that you need compared to the C solution.